# What is a good way destructure two objects into one, joining specific keys?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

Given two objects with different but known keys - which may or may not be set - what is a good way to combine them into one object using specific keymaps for both?

Say, for example, `obj1` can have keys `itemA`, `itemB`, and `itemC`. Another `obj2` can have keys `item_a`, `item_b`, and `item_c`, and takes precedence. The keys refer to the same final keys `a`, `b`, and `c` respectively.

This is what I came up with, but it feels unnecessarily convoluted.

```js
// Given these objects:
const obj1 = { itemA: 1, itemB: 2, itemC: undefined }
const obj2 = { item_a: undefined, item_b: 20, item_c: 30 }

// Desired result: { a: 1, b: 20, c: 30 }

const filter = obj => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(entry => entry[1])
)

const serialized1 = (object => 
    ({ itemA:a, itemB:b, itemC:c } = object) 
    && filter({a, b, c}))(obj1)
const serialized2 = (object => 
    ({ item_a:a, item_b:b, item_c:c } = object) 
    && filter({a, b, c}))(obj2)
const finalObject = { ...serialized1, ...serialized2 }

console.log(finalObject)
// { a: 1, b: 20, c: 30 }
```

I'm roughly trying to have a keymap for each object for which foreign keys map to my local keys, which then merge.

---

**Note:** The mentioned key names are examples. In reality it can be arbitrary, like one of `im-dimensions` and `img-res` being stored in a key called `size`.

Comment: Just for clarification you want to use the higher value if itemX and item_x are both present?

Comment: @Aaron no, the second object takes precedence. Once the keys are equalized, `{ ...serialized1, ...serialized2 }` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Using Stringify and Parse,we can achieve that

```js
const obj1 = { itemA: 1, itemB: 2 };
const obj2 = { item_b: 20, item_c: 30 };
let format=(obj)=>{
 return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).toLowerCase().replace(/\"(\w*)([a-c]{1}\":)/g,"\"$2"));
}
let obj3={...format(obj1),...format(obj2)}
console.log(obj3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Wait.. what? This works indeed. Are you an A.I.? :D You've answered my question exactly. However, I did not mean that the last character is literally the target key. Those were simplified examples. I will upvote your answer because you've answered the question to the letter! If no one comes along with an answer to the spirit of the question, the checkmark will go to you.

Comment: Ok.. How do i change the answer so that you will have your problem solved.. @Redsandro

Comment: if the keys can be specified. E.g. `size` `=` `im-dimensions` `||` `img-res`. Like an object keymap, or a translation array. Something that is maintainable with unexpected key names

Comment: Hi @Supercool. I owe you an answer. Yours did not actually answer the question in a sophisticated reusable way; it worked exclusively with the exact example keys given, not an arbitrary set of keys. I posted a versatile answer below that will work with any map.

Comment: I didn't look into solving your question.i was halfway then something came and I totally forgot. Cool we have a solution now

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. You can create a `map` of oddly named keys to their preferred names, and "rename" them into a new object using the ES6 [Initializer Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer). Basically that means you can use a variable as a key name like so:

```js
const obj = {
    [key]: value
}
```

So with our `map`, we can create a new key with the value from our old object:

```js
const obj = {
    [map[key]]: obj[key]
}
```

In order to automate this for every key in an object, we can use the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function in conjunction with the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax:

```js
const mapper = (map, obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(key => Boolean(obj[key]))
        .reduce((acc, key) =>
            ({
                ...acc,
                ...{ [map[key]]: obj[key] }
            }), {})
```

This is a very versatile and reusable function. All we need is to supply the `map` and the input object. Here's a full example based on the data from the original question:

```js
// Given these objects:
const obj1 = { itemA: 1, itemB: 2, itemC: undefined }
const obj2 = { item_a: undefined, item_b: 20, item_c: 30 }

// Desired result: { a: 1, b: 20, c: 30 }
// ------

// Map keys to predefined attributes
const map = {
itemA: 'a', 
item_a: 'a', 
itemB: 'b', 
item_b: 'b', 
itemC: 'c',
item_c: 'c'
}

const mapper = (map, obj) =>
Object.keys(obj)
    .filter(key => Boolean(obj[key]))
    .reduce((acc, key) =>
        ({
            ...acc,
            ...{ [map[key]]: obj[key] }
        }), {})

const keymap = mapper.bind(null, map)
const attributes = { ...keymap(obj1), ...keymap(obj2) }

console.log(attributes)
// { a: 1, b: 20, c: 30 }
```